# Avoid infinity re-rendering when the children is updating the parent's array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**In the Student (children) component**

- when the value of the variable changes, the `useEffect` hooks will update the parents's array by `handleStudentsChange`, a function provided by the parent component.

**In the Students (parent) component**

- renders a list of Student(children) components
- In attempt to prevent infinity loop, `handleStudentsChange` function defined using the `useCallback` hook. However, it does not seem to be working.

**Problems/Questions**

- `handleStudentsChange` runs infinitely once a change has occur
- Why is that? and How do I fix it?
- Note: I do not want a onSubmit button

See code here:
[I am a CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/student-example-p477vq?file=/src/Students.tsx)

**Student.tsx** (children)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

interface student {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  grade: number;
}

interface studentProps {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  grade: number;
  handleStudentsChange: (index: number, student: student) => void;
}

function Student(props: studentProps) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(props.firstName);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(props.lastName);
  const [grade, setGrade] = useState(props.grade);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleStudentsChange(id, {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      grade: grade
    });
  }, [firstName, lastName, grade, props]);

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        label="firstName"
        onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
        value={firstName}
      />
      <TextField
        label="lastName"
        onChange={(event) => setLastName(event.target.value)}
        value={lastName}
      />
      <TextField
        label="grade"
        onChange={(event) => setGrade(+event.target.value)}
        value={grade}
      />
    </>
  );
```

**Students.tsx** (parent)

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Student from "./Student";

interface student {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  grade: number;
}

export default function Students() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState<student[]>([
    { firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Bieber", grade: 100 },
    { firstName: "Robert", lastName: "Oppenhiemer", grade: 100 }
  ]);

  const handleStudentsChange = useCallback(
    (index: number, updatedStudent: student) => {
      // console.log(index) //I only want this to rerender when the value change however it turn into an infinity loop
      setStudents((prevStudents) => {
        const updatedStudents = [...prevStudents];
        updatedStudents[index] = updatedStudent;
        return updatedStudents;
      });
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <>
      {students.map((student, index) => {
        return (
          <Student
            key={index}
            id={index}
            firstName={student.firstName}
            lastName={student.lastName}
            grade={student.grade}
            handleStudentsChange={(index: number, newStudent: student) =>
              handleStudentsChange(index, newStudent)
            }
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

As shown in the code above, I tried using `React.memo` on the student (children) component and `useCallback` on `handleStudentsChange` expecting the infinity loop will be prevented. However, the infinity loop continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, yours seems an overcomplicated (yet instable) solution.

First off, you want the `Students` component be the "master" of the dataset and that's a good choice. Hence, there's no reason to replicate the state in the Student component: remove the `useState` and straight use the parent one.

Secondly, it has no sense to trigger a value change when there's no change. If you use the `useEffect` in that way, it will trigger an handler call even on the component load, thus no change.

```
function Student(props: studentProps) {
  const { firstName, lastName, grade, handleStudentsChange } = props;

  const handle = (name, value) => {
    handleStudentsChange({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      grade,
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        label="firstName"
        onChange={(event) => handle("firstName", event.target.value)}
        value={firstName}
      />
      <TextField
        label="lastName"
        onChange={(event) => handle("lastName", event.target.value)}
        value={lastName}
      />
      <TextField
        label="grade"
        onChange={(event) => handle("grade", +event.target.value)}
        value={grade}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Then, modify the parent component accordingly:

```
  const handleStudentsChange = (index: number, updatedStudent: student) => 
      // console.log(index) //I only want this to rerender when the value change however it turn into an infinity loop
      setStudents((prevStudents) => {
        const updatedStudents = [...prevStudents];
        updatedStudents[index] = updatedStudent;
        return updatedStudents;
      });
    }

  return (
    <>
      {students.map((student, index) => {
        return (
          <Student
            key={index}
            id={index}
            firstName={student.firstName}
            lastName={student.lastName}
            grade={student.grade}
            handleStudentsChange={(newStudent: student) =>
              handleStudentsChange(index, newStudent)
            }
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

As you may notice, there's no need of `useCallback`.

I don't get what's the role of the "id" property.

The latter snippet could be written in the following more compact way:

```
  return students.map((student, index) => (
          <Student
            key={index}
            id={index}
            {...student}
            handleStudentsChange={(newStudent: student) =>
              handleStudentsChange(index, newStudent)
            }
          />
        ));
```

NOTE: I didn't test the code.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

> `handleStudentsChange` runs infinitely once a change has occur

`handleStudentsChange` doesn't only run infinitely once a change occurs – it runs infinitely from the first render. This is because the `Student` component has a `useEffect` that calls `handleStudentsChange` which updates the state in the `Students` component causing `Student` components to rerender which then calls the `useEffect` again, ad infinitum.

## Solution

You need `handleStudentsChange` to be called only after your inputs have been updated – not after every render. I've included an example below which updates the state in `Students` after the [`blur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) is fired from the input. For more cleverness (and complexity) you could diff the props and state to decide if an update is required but I'll leave that to you to figure out.

```js
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useCallback, useEffect, useState } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { TextField } = MaterialUI;

function Student(props) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(props.firstName);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(props.lastName);
  const [grade, setGrade] = useState(props.grade);
  const handleStudentsChange = props.handleStudentsChange;
  
  const onBlur = () => {
    handleStudentsChange(props.id, {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      grade,
    });
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <TextField
        label="firstName"
        onBlur={onBlur}
        onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
        value={firstName}
      />
      <TextField
        label="lastName"
        onBlur={onBlur}
        onChange={(event) => setLastName(event.target.value)}
        value={lastName}
      />
      <TextField
        label="grade"
        onBlur={onBlur}
        onChange={(event) => setGrade(+event.target.value)}
        value={grade}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

function Students() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([
    { firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Bieber", grade: 100 },
    { firstName: "Robert", lastName: "Oppenhiemer", grade: 100 }
  ]);

  const handleStudentsChange = useCallback(
    (index, updatedStudent) => {
      // console.log(index) // I only want this to rerender when the value change however it turn into an infinity loop
      
      console.log({ updatedStudent });

      setStudents((prevStudents) => {
        const updatedStudents = [...prevStudents];
        updatedStudents[index] = updatedStudent;
        return updatedStudents;
      });
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {students.map((student, index) => {
        return (
          <Student
            key={index}
            id={index}
            firstName={student.firstName}
            lastName={student.lastName}
            grade={student.grade}
            handleStudentsChange={(index, newStudent) =>
              handleStudentsChange(index, newStudent)
            }
          />
        );
      })}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Students />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```