# React TextInput Losing focus on just the letter S

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a TextInput that loses focus only when typing the letter `s`.  Strange all other letters work as expected.

```
<FormControl key={"1"} sx={{ m: 1 }} variant="outlined" onChange={handleFilterValueChange}>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-filter">Filter</InputLabel>
    <OutlinedInput
        id="outlined-filter"
        type={'text'}
        sx={{ width: '100%' }}
        endAdornment={
            <InputAdornment
                position="end">
                <Search />
            </InputAdornment>
        }
        autoFocus
        label="Filter"

    />
</FormControl>
```

After typing `s` the input loses focus causing a blue border to be highlighted around the control.

[image]

If I type the letter `d` or any other letter, followed by `s` it works OK.

[image]

We are using `"@mui/material": "^5.0.0",`

Anyone have any thoughts as to what this might be?  All other Stack posts say something about a component inside a component, and re-render, but I am not seeing how they apply.

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks for all the suggestions to create MRE or move around the code. I think I have the reason for what is causing the strange behavior, although not certain yet why.

Will work on an MRE in the mean time.

After moving the TextInput around, I noticed the behavior worked.  Also commenting out Select All and Clear `<Link>` fixed the problem.

When moving these Links to their own `<Stack>` wrapper, the UI showed how the blue box gave focus to the links.

[image]

Here is a larger view of the code:

```
<Stack direction={"row"} spacing={2} sx={{ m: 1 }}>
      <Link
          variant="body2"
          underline="hover"
      >
          Select all
      </Link>
      <Link
          variant="body2"
          underline="hover"
      >
          Clear
      </Link>
  </Stack>
  <Stack direction={"column"} spacing={0} rowGap={0} sx={{ m: 3 }}>

      <TextField
          id="outlined-filter"
          sx={{ width: '100%' }}
          autoFocus
          label="Filter"
      />
      <List
          dense sx={{
              width: '100%',
              bgcolor: 'background.paper',
              overflow: 'auto',
              maxHeight: 300,
          }}
      >
          {Array.from(timelineProfileConfigurationOptionsLocal?.dimensions).map((p, i) => {
              return (
                  <ListItem
                      key={i}
                      disablePadding
                  >
                      <ListItemButton>
                          <Checkbox
                              edge="start"
                              checked={p.checked}
                          />
                          <ListItemText primary={p.value} />
                      </ListItemButton>
                  </ListItem>
              );
          })}
      </List>
      <Button
          sx={{ mt: 1 }}
          variant="outlined"
          onClick={handleConfigurationSubmit}
      >OK</Button>
  </Stack>
</Menu>
</Stack>
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]!

Comment: Unfortunately our network restricts most of these tools, but perhaps I can widdle something down to a min example

Comment: You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). The Q&A linked has a link to how you can use React within the snippet. Alternatively, as I've created snippets with React + MUI before, you can take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76846788/3050293).

Comment: *All other Stack posts say something about a component inside a component* - this was my first thought as well or that a component is being saved in state or something like that - but without more code we can't really say. Runnable in a snippet or not, I would suggest editing with more code.

Comment: 99% of the time this happens because a component that you expect to be re-rendering is in fact un-mounting and re-mounting. But at this point that's all the help I can give

Comment: Thanks all, I think I am on to something... just above that code is <Link
                                                component="button"
                                                sx={{ textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: '0.9em' }}
                                                onClick={() => handleSelectAllFilterSelection()}
                                            >
                                                Select all
                                            </Link>

I think the <Link> is interfering.

Comment: @ToddWorden I'm not sure I'm following on why that could be the cause. If you're going to pursue a solution by yourself you should probably delete this question. Right now, it doesn't have enough details for others to help, and will probably be closed as such. Personally, I would recommend updating your question with the code you mentioned and maybe even the full component, and then continue to research yourself too

Comment: @BrianThompson There is UPDATE 1 added. Is this what you were suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

After some additional searching, I came across this:

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/19116

Adding `onKeyDown={(e) => { e.stopPropagation()}}` to the Input solved for me.

```
  <FormControl sx={{ m: 1 }} variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-filter">Filter</InputLabel>
      <OutlinedInput
          id="outlined-filter"
          type={'text'}
          sx={{ width: '100%' }}
          endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment
                  position="end">
                  <Search />
              </InputAdornment>
          }
          autoFocus
          label="Filter"
          onChange={handleFilterValueChange}
          onKeyDown={(e) => { e.stopPropagation()}}
      />
  </FormControl>
```